# Своя сортировка в DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Нужно сделать свою сортировку в определенном столбце `DataGrid`.
Данные берутся из  `ObservableCollection`. Столбец содержит строки. Нужно чтобы по клику в заголовке сортировало в том порядке, в котором нужно мне.

Все способы которые пытался найти просто описывают, как сортировать, по возрастанию или по убыванию, ну или я не разобрался. Вот [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956251/sort-a-wpf-datagrid-programmatically/19952233#19952233)

Comment: В каком порядке вам нужно? Или юзер сам должен выбирать фильтр?

Comment: Там есть оверлоад с параметром Comparable, его используйте при сортировке. Там задаёте свое условие сортировки, если память не изменяет.

Comment: @SeeSharp , у меня строки - IP-адрес, он по умолчанию сортирует не правильно. Пробовал использовать класс IpAddress, но там не определен  IComparable. Поэтому либо его определять, либо как-то заставить правильно сортировать строки. Как отсортировать массив со строками IP-адреса я знаю, как прикрутить эту сортировку не знаю

Comment: Возможно вот решение https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129601/how-can-i-apply-a-custom-sort-rule-to-a-wpf-datagrid  Только нужно описать свое comparer = new ResultSort(direction);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скрестил бульдога с носорогом, возможно не совсем корректно и по другим столбцам сортировка не работает, но пока устраивает. upd: универсально сделать не получается, доработал под свои объекты.

```
DataGridDevices.Sorting += new DataGridSortingEventHandler(SortHandler);

void SortHandler(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        var dg = sender as DataGrid;              
        DataGridColumn column = e.Column;
        string dataGridHeaderIP = Globals.DataGridHeaderIP;
        if (column.Header.ToString() == dataGridHeaderIP)
        {
            IComparer comparer = null;
            // prevent the built-in sort from sorting
            e.Handled = true;
            ListSortDirection direction = (column.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending) ? ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;
            //set the sort order on the column
            column.SortDirection = direction;
            //use a ListCollectionView to do the sort.
            ListCollectionView lcv = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dg.ItemsSource);
            //this is my custom sorter it just derives from IComparer and has a few properties
            //you could just apply the comparer but i needed to do a few extra bits and pieces  
            comparer = new SortIPAddress(direction);
            //apply the sort
            lcv.CustomSort = comparer;
        }            
    }

public class SortIPAddress : IComparer
{
    private readonly ListSortDirection direction;

    public SortIPAddress(ListSortDirection direction)
    {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    int IComparer.Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        string xIp = "";
        string yIp = "";
        long nX = 0;
        long nY = 0;

        if (x is Device && y is Device)
        {
            xIp = ((Device)x).Ip;
            yIp = ((Device)y).Ip;                
        }
        else if (x is Event && y is Event)
        {
            xIp = ((Event)x).Ip;
            yIp = ((Event)y).Ip;                
        }

        if (xIp != string.Empty && yIp != string.Empty)
        {
            string[] octetsX = xIp.Split('.');
            string[] octetsY = yIp.Split('.');

            if (octetsX.Count() == 4 && octetsY.Count() == 4)
            {
                nX = long.Parse(octetsX[0]) * 255 * 255 * 255 + long.Parse(octetsX[1]) * 255 * 255 + long.Parse(octetsX[2]) * 255 + long.Parse(octetsX[3]);
                nY = long.Parse(octetsY[0]) * 255 * 255 * 255 + long.Parse(octetsY[1]) * 255 * 255 + long.Parse(octetsY[2]) * 255 + long.Parse(octetsY[3]);
            }
        }

        if (direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            return MyCompare(nX, nY);
        }
        return MyCompare(nX, nY) * -1;
    }

    int MyCompare(long x, long y)
    {
        if (x == y)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (x > y)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно еще проще сделать сравнение, распарсив строку в IPAddress и сравнив как указано тут внизу https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/5f5667

Comment: Как-то бы еще сделать так, чтобы в сравнение попадал не весь объект из которого потом вычленять IP, а только строки сразу.

Comment: В цифру ИП адрес переведите, и по ним сорт.

Comment: @NewView ну я так и сделал ведь. Только в IComparer.Compare попадает объект Device целиком (т.е. вся строка таблицы, а не отдельный столбец). Наверно дело в этом ListCollectionView lcv = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DataGridDevices.ItemsSource);

Comment: Не, все немного проще, ип адрес из объекта приведите к __одной__ цифре, без разбиения по маскам, так кажется попроще будет. Он в объекте IpAddress так и храниться кажется. Давно ACL делал по ИП, там задачи схожие стояли.

Comment: И кстати: `IpAddress, но там не определен IComparable` - метод не сложно и дописать, на самом деле, на основе класса IComparable, тем более что сравнивать надо значения типа `long`.

Comment: @NewView Вот варианты https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461742/how-to-convert-an-ipv4-address-into-a-integer-in-c . Ну или действительно реализовать IComparable для IpAddress